# php login authentication failing

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I'm relatively new to php, and I'm trying to write a really simple login script. I've got the basic functionality down, but I can't login to the system. My login script is below, and my registration script is below as well.

checklogin.php

```
include_once 'inc/db.inc.php';

$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string(md5($_POST['password']));


try {
$sql="SELECT id, username, password FROM users WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";
$result = $pdo->query($sql);
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
// If result matched $username and $password, table row must be 1 row
if($count == 1){

    // Register $username, $password and redirect to file "index.php"
     session_register("username");
     session_register("password"); 
     header("Location: index.php");
 }
 else {
 header("Location: login.php?invalid=1");
 }
}

catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e;
}

ob_end_flush();

?>
```

checkreg.php

```
include_once 'inc/db.inc.php';

 //This makes sure they did not leave any fields blank
 if (!$_POST['username'] | !$_POST['password'] | !$_POST['passwordconf'] ) {
    die('You did not complete all of the required fields');
}

if ($_POST['password'] != $_POST['passwordconf']) {
    die('Your passwords did not match. ');
}

$_POST['password'] = md5($_POST['password']);
if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $_POST['password'] = addslashes($_POST['password']);
    $_POST['username'] = addslashes($_POST['username']);
        }
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

 try {
 // now we insert it into the database
$sql = "INSERT INTO users(username,password) VALUES ('$username','$password')";
$result = $pdo->exec($sql);
header("Location: index.php");

} catch (PDOException $e){
 echo $e;
}
?>
```

I know that the registration is writing to the database, but everytime I attempt a valid login I receive my invalid credentials flag. Anything you can do to help me would be awesome. Thank you.

Comment: Doesn't seem like you stop people from registering the same username/password combo. Do you happen to have the same combo more than once in the table? That would stop $count from being 1, and cause what you're seeing.

Comment: Have you tried to echo out the username and password after a login attempt to see if they match within your database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue could be with **session_register()**, depending on the version of PHP you're using. Try putting

```
    session_start();
```

At the top of **checklogin.php**, then using

```
    ...
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
    ...
```

instead of **session_register()**.

Comment: `code`session_start();
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string(md5($_POST['password']));
try {
 $sql="SELECT id, username, password FROM pinters WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";
 $result = $pdo->query($sql);
 $count=mysql_num_rows($result);
 if($count = 0){
  $_SESSION["username"] = $username;
   $_SESSION["password"] = "validated";
   header("Location: index.php");
  }
  else {
  echo $username;
  echo $password;
  // header("Location: login.php?invalid=1");
  }
}

Comment: still doesn't authenticate

Comment: just to try it, 'echo $_SESSION["username"]'. If that doesn't show anything, the POST data just isn't getting to your checklogin.php, which may be a typo in your login form

Comment: looks like you are dead on. It's not posting to checklogin page.

Comment: @user2116751 ah well I hope that helps things

Comment: Nope...still broke. But I have a new direction to work in, but the form seems fine. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Got it... the count wasn't being passed. Had to use the following PDO count string:

    $count=$result->rowCount();

Now it works like a champ. Thanks to everyone for their assistance.

Answer (score 0):

First you should clear some things out:

1.

```
if (!$_POST['username'] | !$_POST['password'] | !$_POST['passwordconf'] ) {
die('You did not complete all of the required fields');}
```

it should be && and not |.

1. In your code there's nowhere to check if username exists or not, so i'm guessing that you have multiple users with the same username. Before inserting in your checkreg.php, you should fist check if the username exists or not.
2. in your checklogin.php change if($count == 1) to if($count > 0)

If this not helped could you give me more information like database data (the data that is in your database now)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// Use of session_register() is deprecated
$barney = "A big purple dinosaur.";
session_register("barney");

// Use of $_SESSION is preferred, as of PHP 4.1.0
$_SESSION["zim"] = "An invader from another planet.";

// The old way was to use $HTTP_SESSION_VARS
$HTTP_SESSION_VARS["spongebob"] = "He's got square pants.";
?>
```

**Warning:**

This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things to try:

1) The session_register function call is deprecated. http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-register.php. You really ought to be using $_SESSION if at possible.

Something like this:

```
 $_SESSION["username"] = $username;
 $_SESSION["password"] = "validated"; // md5 is variable so you can't easily check for it on next page render
```

2) When testing for the values, you don't want $_POST, you want to use $_SESSION again on the next page render. Something like this:

```
if ("validated" == $_SESSION["password"]) {
    // You're logged in...
}
```

3) Note, for the $_SESSION array to be populated you must call session_start(); once and only once before use. (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php for more.)

4) I know this is sample code, but SQL Injection attack possible. Need to escape those variables.

$sql="SELECT id, username, password FROM users WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";

Comment: made the changes that you guys suggested but I'm still having an issue. Instead of doing the redirect to the invalid login, i am now echoing the username and password. But nothing shows up.

Comment: It's feels like there should be a 3rd block of code which is missing. What isn't there is checking to see if you're already logged in by looking at the $_SESSION variables before launching into looking up the password in checklogin.php.